# Before insert with million of records on custom object

Tags: apex, trigger, batch, before-trigger

Hi we have requirement where an external system will call Salesforce to insert millions of records in a custom object. External System will send contactAddress id in SOAP request. I need to make sure before it insert records in custom object, particular contactAddress id provided in SOAP Request must present in contact object already. 
Another process might have already synch contact details with contactAddress Id but this is to make sure that the contactAddress Id is already present.

I thought of writing Before Insert Trigger on custom object which will be calling batch apex to check the existence of contactAddress Id in Contact. I know I will hit the limit with this.

Any other approach or suggestions? Much appreciated.

Comment: This is something that's really going to need to be integrated as part of your batch class, not something you can do independently. Its more a matter of deciding how you're going to handle errors with records that don't have a valid external Id, and will thus fail. Will you want to fail the entire batch, report the error and proceed, throw an exception, or if you report the error, who/how will it be handled?

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev this is a first part of story, another part is, if contactAddress Id doesn't exist then i shall poll contact object at some duration to check if anytime that contactAddress Id is inserted in contact object. I think this is more complicated..

Comment: Agree, this is not a simple question to answer. This is an integration issue and not one of which trigger do I write, etc. You have a data error handling, exception handling and general error handling issue to consider as part of an entire application that needs to be handled on both ends since there's 2-way communication that needs to take place as data is transferred in batches. Take a look at Integration Patterns & Practices in the Developer Docs as starting resource.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, However Calling [Batch apex](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) would not gurantee that record already created before insert because it will be asynch.

Even millions of records are inserted by external system, Salesforce will execute it in batch of 200.

You will need one SOQL which will return `Map<Id,contactAddress>` and you can use map to see if it contains ID or not, then create list of record needs to be created and use 1 DML operation to create.

However, you may fall into limits if `contactAddress` also has before insert trigger and performing heavy job.

I would suggest to think on [Upsert operation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_dml_upsert.htm) as well, so you will need less coding  at SFDC end.

There may be other challenges also, so would suggest complete design discussion with integration team.

Comment: Thanks @jitendra for the approach you have  suggested. I have not yet implemented anything so no idea but I will be keep in mind to see if that works. This is still into discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already planning to use a batch class to process these records, you must not be expecting to send this validation back in a synchronous response. This may be a good case to have a separate custom object used for staging purposes: `Staging_Custom_Object__c`, that just receives the incoming data. This object should have fields for everything received through the SOAP request, along with Status and Status Detail fields.

After receiving new staging records your batch class runs over the Status=New rows in the staging table, and either creates a proper custom object record based on the staging record fields (Status="Processed") or notes a validation error(e.g. Status="Error", Status Detail="Invalid contactAddress").

When staging rows have an error status, you could have a workflow rule fire an email notification, or set up Reports/List Views/Dashboards to show Errors. Or anything you dream of through Apex, of course.

In this way, you avoid creating rows in your custom object table that don't have enough data to be valid, and can perform your detailed validation/processing asynchronously after the insert transaction. This approach is simplest when the table is only used through insertion, even if the goal is to update an existing record. Updating existing records based on matching data from the staging table is left as an exercise for the reader, unless you would like more information about that.

Comment: How about if external system checks the existence of contactAddress Id? External system will be using ETL to insert records in custom object. Isn't it more easier for ETL to add this check?

Comment: I guess it depends on where you want to implement the complexity of the checking logic. I am assuming here that your external system does nothing but this transaction. However, if you can validate your data before sending it to Salesforce, including keeping a "holding pen" for records that are waiting for contactAddress to show up, that may make more sense for you. In that case, you don't need validation in Salesforce at all.